# How do I order objects that are using setState declared in the root component into different files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling on reorganizing my application written in React.
This is a particular case where I didn't find any specific answer to resolve my issue.

I've been developing my main state's attributes on root component by grouping them by context(not react context) and propagate their contents from node to child nodes like this:

```
// AppOperator.jsx which is root component
class AppOperator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // first group, attributes and methods regarding cart management
        this.CartManager = {
            list: [],
            methodCM1: this.methodCM1.bind(this),
            methodCM2: this.methodCM2.bind(this),
        };
        // second group, properties related to phase management
        this.PhaseManager = {
            step: 0,
            methodPM: this.methodPM.bind(this),
            nextPhase: this.nextPhase.bind(this),
        };

        this.state = {
            CartManager: this.CartManager,
            PhaseManager: this.PhaseManager,
        }
    }

    render = () => <View CartManager={this.state.CartManager} {/*...(etc)*/} />

    // ...
    // CartManager methods
    methodCM1 = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { CartManager } = state;
        CartManager.list = [];
        return state;
    });

    methodCM2 = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { CartManager } = state;
        CartManager.discount = 0.5;
        return state;
    }, () => this.methodPM());

    // ...
    // PhaseManager methods
    methodPM = () => this.nextPhase();

    nextPhase = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { PhaseManager } = state;
        PhaseManager.step++;
        return state;
    });

    // ...
    // Methods for.... nth object
    // ...
}
```

As you can see there might be methods from different object called inside.
There would not be a problem if you leave their declaration inside the same scope (`this instanceOf AppOperator`). They would act as 'global' variables. Everyone sees everyone.

But what if it keeps growing and get more complex? How can you maintain such thing?

First thing, I would start using React Context instead of propagating the objects from node to node. No problem with that.

I would then start splitting the objects in different files and call their costructors inside component AppOperator like this:

```
// AppOperator.jsx
import { CartManager, PhaseManager, } from './Managers';

class AppOperator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // this looks pretty pabolouuus!.
        this.state = {
            CartManager: new CartManager(),
            PhaseManager: new PhaseManager(),
            ['nth-object']: new NthStateObject(),
        }
    }

    render = () => <View CartManager={this.state.CartManager} {/*...(etc)*/} />
}
```

and Managers like this:

```
// CartManager.js
export default class CartManager {
    constructor() {
        this.list = [];
        this.discount = 0;
    }

    methodCM1 = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { CartManager } = state;
        CartManager.list = [];
        return state;
    });

    methodCM2 = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { CartManager } = state;
        CartManager.discount = 0.5;
        return state;
    }, () => this.methodPM());
}

// PhaseManager.js
export default class PhaseManager{
    constructor() {
        this.step = 0;
    }

    methodPM = () => this.nextPhase();

    nextPhase = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { PhaseManager } = state;
        PhaseManager.step++;
        return state;
    });
}
```

This would be a cool solution if it could work.
Splitting like so, would leave managers' methods to call setState without knowing AppOperator context.

Instead, binding object's method with AppOperator context would abandon their own properties out and that's also not good:

```
// PhaseManager.js
export default class PhaseManager{
    constructor(that) { // easy not working cheat
        this.step = 0;
        this.methodPM = this.methodPM.bind(that);
        this.nextPhase = this.nextPhase .bind(that);
    }

    methodPM = () => this.nextPhase();

    nextPhase = () => this.setState((state) => {
        const { PhaseManager } = state;
        PhaseManager.step++;
        return state;
    });
}
```

Then, How would you approach this problem? Would you leave it like that, knowing that it might be unmaintanable in future?

Comment: So you want to share one state across different elements on the site right?

Comment: Yes, thats my requirement. But I would like to import the object from another file. The object has also methods that calls setState